# Angular Unit Test: Moking Service inside a service or moking an abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to test a service that extends a abstract class. This abstract class implements the constructor and the method `getId`.

Follows the code:

```
export abstract class ClientCacheService {
    private subscriptionId: string;

    protected getId(key :string, prefix:string=""): string {
        return `${this.subscriptionId}_${prefix}_${key}`;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.subscriptionId = new AppContextService().organizationKey();
    }

    abstract setCache(key :string, prefix:string, object: ICacheble): void;
    abstract getCache(key :string, prefix:string): ICacheble | null;
    abstract removeCache(key :string, prefix:string): void;
}

@Injectable()
export class MemoryCacheService extends ClientCacheService {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    setCache(key: string, prefix: string, object: ICacheble): void {
        window[this.getId(key, prefix)] = JSON.stringify(object);
    }    
    getCache(key: string, prefix: string): ICacheble | null {
        let res = window[this.getId(key, prefix)];
        return res ? JSON.parse(res) : null;
    }
    removeCache(key: string, prefix: string): void {
        delete window[this.getId(key, prefix)];
    }
}
```

I have two options:

1. Mock the `ClientCacheService`
2. Mock the `AppContextService` that is incide of the constructure `ClientCacheService`

What I want is the second option (mock the `AppContextService`), but I could accept the first option as well as a good answer.

As you can see in the following code, I give a try on mocking the `ClientCacheService`, but the MemoryCacheService does not has a `subscriptionId` defined, making my 'should be possible set cache' test case wrong.

```
import { MemoryCacheService } from "./memory-cache.service";
import { ICacheble } from "interfaces/cacheble.interface";
import { TestBed, inject } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { ClientCacheService } from "./client-cache.service";

export class CacheableObject implements ICacheble {
    prop1: String;
    prop2: Boolean;
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = "prop1 testable";
        this.prop2 = true;
    }
    equals(cacheableObject: CacheableObject): boolean {
        return this.prop1 === cacheableObject.prop1 &&
               this.prop2 === cacheableObject.prop2;
    }
}

export class MockClientCacheService {
    private subscriptionId: string;
    constructor() {
        this.subscriptionId = "Just a subscription";
    }
}

describe('MemoryCacheService Test cases', () => {
    let memoryCacheService: MemoryCacheService;
    beforeEach(()=> {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: ClientCacheService, useClass: MockClientCacheService },
                MemoryCacheService
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should be possible instantiate it', inject([MemoryCacheService], (memoryCacheService:MemoryCacheService)=> {
        expect(memoryCacheService).toBeDefined();
    }));

    it('should be possible set cache',()=> {
        let cacheableObject: CacheableObject = new CacheableObject();
        memoryCacheService.setCache("test_key", "test_prefix", cacheableObject);
        let storedObject: CacheableObject = memoryCacheService.getCache("test_key", "test_prefix") as CacheableObject;
        expect(storedObject.equals(cacheableObject)).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem** is in mocking `ClientCacheService` in providers array: `{ provide: ClientCacheService, useClass: MockClientCacheService }`.

**Proof**: if you try to add console.log inside the `MockClientCacheService` constructor - you'll never see the output in the console, i.e. the `MemoryCacheService` service still extends original `abstract class ClientCacheService` (you also can console.log inside the `ClientCacheService` constructor and it will be logged to the console).

**Explanation**: when you add `{ provide: ClientCacheService, useClass: MockClientCacheService }` this will work ONLY when the Dependency Injector is aware of your service. But in your code the `abstract class ClientCacheService` "lives" outside the DI world and this why you cannot mock it inside the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` method.

**Workaround solution**: you can test your classes separately. For example write a couple of tests for the abstract class itself (follow [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500351/jasmine-unit-test-abstract-class) to find out more details on testing abstract class). And then you can write unit tests for derived class `MemoryCacheService`.

**Potential issue**: in your example the `abstract class ClientCacheService` constructor creates new instance of `AppContextService` which makes too difficult to mock `AppContextService` class. As a tradeoff you can refactor the code and inject `AppContextService`:

```
export abstract class ClientCacheService {
  ...    
  constructor(appContextService: AppContextService) {
    this.subscriptionId = appContextService.organizationKey();
  }
  ...
}
```

And then you have to pass the `appContextService` instance to the super constructor like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MemoryCacheService extends ClientCacheService {
  constructor(private appContextService: AppContextService) {
    super(appContextService);
  }
  ...
}
```